# How to find List Tables using columns value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-schema

I have 500+ tables in database. All tables have several columns. Among them Some tables have 'CMDFLAG' column and value of the columns may have 'C'or'D' or 'M'.

My requirement is to find the list of tables where CMDFLAG is 'C'or'D' or 'M'.

```
Table Name    Column Name   Value
----------     -----------   -----
Table_A         CMDFLAG      C
Table_A         CMDFLAG      D
Table_A         CMDFLAG      M
Table_B         CMDFLAG      C
Table_B         CMDFLAG      D
Table_C         CMDFLAG      M
```

so on ...

I can find list of tables these have CMDFLAG column using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. But I Want to find list of tables where CMDFLAG columns have value 'C'or'D' or 'M'.

I have gone through several questions but can't fulfill my requirement. Moreover I want to use simple query not procedure.

Comment: This is **NOT** a simple query.

Comment: The only way I know of how to do such a thing is to use dynamic sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I have to use dynamic query and temp tables as `EXEC` does not work for common table expressions.

```
CREATE TABLE #t1
(
    tableName varchar(30),
    RN INT
)

CREATE TABLE #t2
(
    tableName varchar(30),
    columnName varchar(30),
    value char(1)
)

INSERT INTO #t1
SELECT C.TABLE_NAME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TABLE_NAME) AS RN
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
WHERE C.COLUMN_NAME = 'CMDFLAG'

DECLARE @COUNT AS INT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #t1)
DECLARE @Iterator AS INT = 1
DECLARE @tableName AS VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @script AS  VARCHAR(200)

WHILE @Iterator <= @COUNT
BEGIN
    SELECT @tableName = (SELECT tableName FROM #t1 WHERE RN = @Iterator)
    SELECT @script = 'SELECT '''+@tableName+''', ''CMDFLAG'', CMDFLAG FROM '+@tableName+' GROUP BY CMDFLAG'

    INSERT INTO #t2
    EXEC(@script)

    SELECT @Iterator = @Iterator + 1

END

SELECT * FROM #t2

DROP TABLE #t1
DROP TABLE #t2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @colname SYSNAME='CMDFLAG';

CREATE TABLE #tablenames(tablename SYSNAME,colname SYSNAME,colval NVARCHAR(128));
DECLARE @dsql NVARCHAR(MAX)= (
    SELECT 
        N'INSERT INTO #tablenames(tablename,colname,colval)'+
        N'SELECT DISTINCT ' +
            'tablename='''+REPLACE(t.TABLE_NAME,N'''',N'''''')+N''','+
            'colname='''+REPLACE(@colname,N'''',N'''''')+N''','+
            'colval='+QUOTENAME(@colname)+N' '+
        N'FROM '+QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_SCHEMA)+N'.'+QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_NAME)+N' '+
        N'WHERE '+QUOTENAME(@colname)+N' IN (''C'',''D'',''M'');'
    FROM 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c ON
            c.TABLE_SCHEMA=t.TABLE_SCHEMA AND
            c.TABLE_NAME=t.TABLE_NAME
    WHERE
        t.TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' AND
        c.COLUMN_NAME=@colname
    FOR 
        XML PATH('')
);

EXECUTE sp_executesql @dsql;

SELECT * FROM #tablenames ORDER BY tablename;
DROP TABLE #tablenames;
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice try. But it returns only list of tables. However as said before,  I need both TableName , ColumnName , Value.

Comment: @AbdurRahman So each column in those tables would only contain one distinct value for CMDFLAG? Or do you want an entry for each distinct value of CMDFLAG in that column?

Comment: ,,  an entry for each distinct value of CMDFLAG in that column

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
DECLARE @ColumnName sysname = 'CMDFLAG', @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

IF OBJECT_ID(N'TempDB.dbo.#Results', N'U') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE #Results(TableName SYSNAME, RowCounts INT)
ELSE
    TRUNCATE TABLE #Results

SELECT
    @Sql = 'INSERT INTO #Results '
            + STUFF((
                        SELECT
                            'UNION ALL SELECT Table_Name = ' 
                                + QUOTENAME(C.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + C.TABLE_NAME, '''') 
                                + ', NumRows = COUNT(*)'
                                + ' FROM ' 
                                + QUOTENAME(C.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' 
                                + QUOTENAME(C.TABLE_NAME )
                                + ' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME) + ' IN(''C'', ''D'', ''M'') '
                                + ' GROUP BY ' + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME)
                                + ' HAVING COUNT(*) > 0 '
                        FROM
                            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
                            CROSS APPLY
                            (
                                SELECT
                                    T.TABLE_SCHEMA, T.TABLE_NAME
                                FROM
                                    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
                                WHERE
                                    T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                                    AND T.TABLE_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA
                                    AND T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
                            ) T
                        WHERE
                            C.COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnName
            FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 10, '')

EXEC(@Sql)
SELECT * FROM #Results
```

### **UPDATE**

Ok this should do what you want:

```
DECLARE @ColumnName sysname = 'CMDFLAG', @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

IF OBJECT_ID(N'TempDB.dbo.#Results', N'U') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE #Results(TableName SYSNAME, ColumnName sysname, Value NVARCHAR(25))
ELSE
    TRUNCATE TABLE #Results

SELECT
    @Sql = 'INSERT INTO #Results '
            + STUFF((
                        SELECT
                            'UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT Table_Name = ' 
                                + QUOTENAME(C.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + C.TABLE_NAME, '''') 
                                + ', '  + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME, '''')
                                + ', '  + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME)
                                + ' FROM ' 
                                + C.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' 
                                + C.TABLE_NAME 
                                + ' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME) + ' IN(''C'', ''D'', ''M'') '
                        FROM
                            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
                            CROSS APPLY
                            (
                                SELECT
                                    T.TABLE_SCHEMA, T.TABLE_NAME
                                FROM
                                    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
                                WHERE
                                    T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                                    AND T.TABLE_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA
                                    AND T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
                            ) T
                        WHERE
                            C.COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnName
            FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 10, '')
EXEC(@Sql)
SELECT * FROM #Results
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice try. But it returns only list of tables. However as said before,  I need both TableName , ColumnName , Value.

Comment: Updated Answer my answer